# where to find home directory when ubuntu installed with wubi

Tags: configuration, wubi, home-directory

Ive installed ubuntu-32bit on windows7-32bit with wubi. Before that I had only ubuntu on my hard disk. It seems like my "home"-folder is the same as my windows home folder. Do I put config files in there? It seems like the directory structure is different than I had before when I only had ubuntu OS on my hard disk. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question, so I'm afraid my answer will include a bit of irrelevant information.

When you use Wubu, Ubuntu resides in a disk image, which lives as a single file on your Windows partition (`c:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`).  Your Ubuntu home folder is there too.  This, by the way, makes all disk access much slower when you've booted Ubuntu through Wubi, compared to a native installation, or at least that's my impression.

When you've actually booted into Ubuntu, you can access the Windows filesystem at `/host`, which is the only directory structure difference that I can think of.  (When you use a regular Ubuntu installation alongside Windows, in a dual-boot configuration, the Windows filesystem is usually at `/media/disk` or something similar.)

I haven't played with a Wubi system in a long while, but I find it easy to believe that Wubi creates a symbolic link (or a few) from your Ubuntu home directory to your Windows home folder.  I don't think the entire home directory will be shared -- Ubuntu and Windows use different filesystems that support different features, have different filename restrictions, etc -- but I suppose the Desktop folder might be.